# Irreducible components of an Algebraic subset.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

This is question 1.27 from Fulton's textbook: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf (the very top of page 9).

> 1.27. Let $V, W$ be algebraic sets in $\mathbb{A}^n(k)$, with $V\subset W$. Show that each irreducible
>   component of $V$ is contained in some irreducible component of $W$.

By a theorem, we have the unique writing $W = \displaystyle\bigcup_{i=0}^{n} w_i$ where the $w_i$ are disjoint and irreducible.

My idea is that for $V$ we will have $V = \displaystyle\bigcup_{i=0}^{n} (V\cap w_i)$ where the $(V\cap w_i)$ are the irreducible components. It's clear that their union is $V$ and that they are mutually disjoint, but I have no idea how to prove they are irreducible. I have tried assuming there are algebraic sets such that $A\cup B = V \cap w_i$ for fixed $i$, and hoping to contradict the irreducibility of $w_i$ with some set algebra, but I didn't get very far.

My question boils down to: Are these the irreducible components of $V$? (and if so, how could I show they are irreducible?) If not, hints towards a solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello: The $w_i$ are not necessarily disjoint. For example the irreducible componets of $\{(x,y):xy=0\}$ are the lines $x=0$ and $y=0$. Think this: each irreducible component of $V$ is an irreducible closed subset of $W$. Now, use the definition of irreducible components of $W$.

Comment: For your second statement: If $V=\{(x,y):xy=0\}$ and $W=\mathbb{A}^2(k)$, then $W$ is irreducible but $W\cap V$ is not.

Comment: For hints towards a solution, you can first try to prove that the set of irreducible closed subsets of an algebraic set satisfies the ascending chain condition (all closed subsets satisfy DCC.) This is equivalent to saying that the set of prime ideals in a finitely generated ring over $k$ satisfy the DCC. Now, use this to find a maximal irreducible closed subset containing any given irreducible closed subset in $W$.

Answer (score 1):

Just to sum up some discussion from the comments: your idea doesn't quite work but it's not so far off, either. A good example of something reducible is the the cross cut out by $xy = 0$ in $\mathbb{A}^2$. It has two irreducible components which meet at the origin, whereas the plane is irreducible.

However, you can show -- and Fulton likely uses this to prove the uniqueness of the irreducible components -- that if $X$ is irreducible and contained in a finite union of closed subsets $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ then $X$ has to be contained in one of the $Y_i$; this might remind you of a fact about prime numbers.